# Efficient way to dynamically populate ListBox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, dynamic, listbox

I have a program that allows a user to search for a customer by name. The way I have done this so far (code below) is have the user start typing the customer name in a TextBox (tbCust), the code fires on the TextChanged event and repopulates the ListBox based on what the user has typed. I think the idea here is obvious and commonly used.

This works without minimal lag on my computer but on some other users computers which are more base level machines, there is anywhere from 100ms to 300ms delay between updates which makes for a pretty crappy user experience.

Correct me if i'm wrong here but I feel like this functionality should be easily attainable without any perceived lag for just about any computer out there.

I assume there is a more correct/efficient way of doing this that I'm just not smart enough to come up with on my own (enter, all of you!)

Please shed some light on maybe a more 'appropriate' way of doing this that results in much better performance. I assume my problem lies with querying the database each time the routine runs (every time the user types a letter) but I'm not sure how else to do it while still working with live data.

Many Many Thanks in Advance!

Video of acceptable performance on my computer: [Youtube Video #1](https://youtu.be/o2ouNLOfWw8)

Video of unacceptable performance on user computer: [YouTube Video #2](https://youtu.be/yTUjpRqhHxs)

User Computer Specs: [image: User Computer Specs]

```
    Private Sub tbCust_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbCust.TextChanged
    'This populates the Customer Selection list box with customers whose names start with the
    'string of letters in the customer name text box.


    If tbCust.TextLength > 0 Then
        lbCustSelect.Visible = True
        Dim SQL As String
        SQL = "SELECT C_CUSTOMER as ID, C_SHIPNAME as Name FROM CUSTOMER WHERE LEFT(C_SHIPNAME," & tbCust.TextLength & ") ='" & tbCust.Text & "'"
        'Query Database
        AeroDBcon.RunQuery(SQL)

        'Fill DataTable with Query results
        dtCustomers = AeroDBcon.DBds.Tables(0)

        'Tie DataTable to ListBox
        lbCustSelect.DataSource = dtCustomers
        lbCustSelect.DisplayMember = "Name"
        lbCustSelect.ValueMember = "ID"

        'If there are no results, hide the ListBox
        If dtCustomers.Rows.Count = 0 Then
            lbCustSelect.Visible = False
        End If
    Else
        'if there is no text in the customer name text box, hide the listbox
        lbCustSelect.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't make repeated calls to the database.  Load everything into a DataTable and then use a [DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview?view=netframework-4.8) as the DataSource.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? I suggest to use LIKE instead of that LEFT .... also set the DataSource after you have set the DisplayMember and ValueMember to avoid a double binding of your data

Comment: TextChanged event handler runs on the UI thread so once you type a key, immediately the UI will freeze to process the query. You should run this on a non-UI thread, signaling to the UI with the results once complete, and the UI will run smoothly. Also to reduce the load on the server / network you may want to start a 100ms timer on keypress which resets on each subsequent keypress prior to expiration, and which runs the query upon expiration, see https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/34360/delay-on-keystroke-when-search-as-you-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filtering in SQL is usually quicker than filtering on client side. But since table CUSTOMER is probably not that large, and there seems to be an overhead issue with querying the database, let's query it all at once, and filter on the client side.

I like strong-typing. Even though you don't use an ORM, we can still create a class to hold your results:

```vb
Private Class Customer
    Public Property ID As String
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

And if we hold a collection of all customers,

```
Private customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer)
```

it's simply filtered like this

```
Dim filteredCustomers = customers.Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith(filterString)).ToList()
```

Also, I wouldn't run the query on keypress. Nor would I run it on the UI thread (UI event handlers run on the UI, and that will cause your UI to freeze while the query runs). Run the query after a set amount of time since the last keypress, and run it off the UI. A `System.Threading.Timer` is perfect for this.

```vb
Private ReadOnly queryTimer As New System.Threading.Timer(AddressOf executeQuery, Nothing, -1, -1)
Private ReadOnly keyPressDelay As Integer = 100
Private customers As IEnumerable(Of Customer)
Private filterString As String = ""

Private Sub tbCust_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tbCust.TextChanged
    filterString = tbCust.Text
    lbCustSelect.Visible = filterString.Length > 0
    If filterString.Length > 0 Then queryTimer.Change(keyPressDelay, -1)
End Sub

Private Sub executeQuery(state As Object)
    ' this could alternately be run in Form_Load
    If customers Is Nothing Then
        Dim sql = "SELECT C_CUSTOMER as ID, C_SHIPNAME as Name FROM CUSTOMER"
        AeroDBCon.RunQuery(sql)
        customers =
            AeroDBCon.DBds.Tables(0).
            AsEnumerable().Select(Function(dr) New Customer With {.ID = dr("ID").ToString(), .Name = dr("Name").ToString()})
    End If

    Dim filteredCustomers = customers.Where(Function(c) c.Name.StartsWith(filterString)).ToList()
    ' Dim filteredCustomers = customers.Where(Function(c) c.Name.Contains(filterString)).ToList()

    ' update the control on the UI thread
    lbCustSelect.Invoke(
        Sub()
            lbCustSelect.DataSource = Nothing
            lbCustSelect.DisplayMember = "Name"
            lbCustSelect.ValueMember = "ID"
            lbCustSelect.DataSource = filteredCustomers
        End Sub)
End Sub
```

You should also dispose the timer when the form disposes. Modify your Dispose method to this

```vb
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing Then
            components?.Dispose()
            queryTimer?.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub
```